# How Should I modify a Big File with Specific Column and Value Using awk?

Tags: shell, awk

Here I have a dataset that includes header and separator, like this:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g
1|2|3|4|5|6|5
2|4|2|3|5|2|1
```

And another config file with some columns and values, like this:

```
b:5
d:6
```

My aim is to modify the dataset with the config file. The result is like this:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g    
1|5|3|6|5|6|5
2|5|2|6|5|2|1
```

Without using "for" outside awk, how can I complete the process?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you could do it using awk:

```
awk '
     NR == FNR { rep[$1] = $2; next } 
     FNR == 1 { for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i in rep) cols[i] = rep[$i] }
     FNR > 1 { for (i in cols) $i = cols[i] }
     1
' FS=':' replacements FS='|' OFS='|' dataset
```

- first, save all of the `key:value` replacements into an array `rep`

  - target the first file using the standard `NR == FNR` (total line number equals this file's line number)
  - skip the rest of the script with `next`
- for the first line of the dataset (second file), work out which columns contain the headers, saving them to `cols` along with their replacements
- for the rest of the lines of the dataset, substitute the columns with their replacement values
- print all lines of the second file using the condition `1` (always true), which triggers the default action `{ print }`

Note that since the two files have different separators, these are specified as arguments after the awk script. `FS` defines the input Field Separator and `OFS` defines the Output Field Separator for the next filename argument. The arguments should be read like:

```
# read the file 'replacements' with input field separator set to ':'
FS=':' replacements
# read the file 'dataset' with input and output field separator set to '|'
FS='|' OFS='|' dataset
```

#### Testing it out

```
$ cat replacements 
b:5
d:6
$ cat dataset 
a|b|c|d|e|f|g
1|2|3|4|5|6|5
2|4|2|3|5|2|1
$ awk '
>      NR == FNR { rep[$1] = $2; next } 
>      FNR == 1 { for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i in rep) cols[i] = rep[$i] }
>      FNR > 1 { for (i in cols) $i = cols[i] }
>      1
> ' FS=':' replacements FS='|' OFS='|' dataset
a|b|c|d|e|f|g
1|5|3|6|5|6|5
2|5|2|6|5|2|1
```

Comment: Thanks! Details are very appreciated. But I still don't get the last line. I understand the meaning of separator, but the definition of `rep ` is placed at last?

Comment: @Kadakyo I'm not really sure what you mean but I edited to explain the last line. It has nothing to do with `rep`.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably wisest to do in the following order. First, you parse the config (assuming GNU dialect of awk):

```
gawk -F \| -v OFS=\| 'NR == FNR { # this pattern trigs inside the first file
    split($0, mapping, /:/)
    rules[mapping[1]] = mapping[2]
    next # short-circuit to skip other blocks
}
```

Next, on the first line of the data file you need to parse column headers:

```
FNR == 1 {
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if($i in rules) forcedValues[i] = rules[$i]
    print
    next
}
```

Now you have an array `forcedValues` that, for some column numbers from 1 through 7 (in your example), contains values those columns should be reset to. So now you process the rest of the file:

```
{
    for(i in forcedValues) $i = forcedValues[i]
    print
}' config.txt input.txt > output.txt
```

(The three code snippets in this post are actually parts of a single shell command and should be concatenated via newlines.)